# How to handle futures that return options in a for comprehension

Tags: scala, future

My services are returning Future[Option[Entity]] and I am currently doing this:

```
val user = userService.getById(1)
val company = userService.getById(1)

if(user.get.companyId == company.get.id) {
   save(...)

   if(...) {
      blahService.boo();   
   }

   return ...
} else 
{
  ...
  return ...
}
```

Now if I refactor this to a for-comprehension, how do I handle the else clause?  Do I return something from the for-comp and then use that like the 'else' clause?

Also, how do I get rid of the .get from inside the for compr?

```
for {
  userOption <- userService.getById(1)
  companyOption <- cService.getById(2)
  if (userOption.get.companyId == companyOption.get.id)
} {
      ..
      ..
      saveUser(userOption.get, companyOption.get)
      return ..
}
```

1. So I am trying to get rid of my .get calls when using the for-comp., how?
2. How do I handle the else clause that I initially had?
3. Is it bad practise to have a for-comp inside of another for-comp?
4. In the above code I have a if(...) and then I call           blahService.boo().  If this is returnign a future, how do I call this without letting the code below execute before this?  Since it is a 'if' it is confusing me.

Comment: I don't see any `Future[Option]`, `userService.getById(_)` returns an `Option` right?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov sorry I meant Future[Option[User]] or whatever the Entity is.

Comment: Check out https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3r5ii6/on_handling_futureeithera_b_sequencing/.

Comment: No worries, I just meant that in the first example `userService.getById(1)` and `user.get` implies that `user` is an `Option`, while in the second one `userService.getById(1)` must be returning a `Future`. So as if the types are different.

Comment: In your example you don't cover the case where `userService.getById(1)` returns `None` -> `.get` on it will throw.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Scalaz's `OptionT`:

```
import scalaz.OptionT.optionT

(for {
  user <- optionT(userService.getById(1))
  company <- optionT(cService.getById(2))
  if (user.companyId == company.id)
} yield {
  saveUser(user, company)
}).run
```

See e.g. this discussion for more: http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/scala-compose-option-future/

Comment: is scalaz safe for production?

Comment: Yes scalaz is safe for production. Many libraries depend on it so you might actually already have it on the classpath. If you don't want to use, check the provided link to see how you can write your own composed type instead of using the generic transformers from scalaz.

Comment: Will this handle the unhappy path?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to mixing `Future`s with control flow, I highly recommend [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/async). I find it to be almost strictly better than `map` or `for`-comprehensions for `Future`s. There are some limitation to what control flow structures you can use, but for your situation, it would work great:

```
async {
  val userOption = await(userService.getById(1))
  val companyOption = await(cService.getById(2))

  (userOption, companyOption) match {
    case (Some(user), Some(company)) => // happy path
    case _ => // sad path
  }
}
```

This whole `async {...}` block is of type `Future[A]`, where `A` is determined by the branches of the `match`.

Comment: Does the playframework use scala-async?  Looks familiar.

Comment: @Blankman Not natively, that I know of. But it certainly comes in handy in Play apps for making and consuming async API requests within request handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to vanilla Scala,

```
val x = for {
  userOption    <- userService.getById(1)
  companyOption <- cService.getById(2)

} yield {
  for {
    user    <- userOption
    company <- companyOption
  } yield {
    if (user.id == company.id) { ... }
    else { ... }
  }
}
x
```

then this is as simple as you can get.

Note that the resulting `Future` will fail if one of the two calls returns a `Failure`. Also, the resulting `Option` will be `None` if one of the call returns `None`. This comprehension is basically good only for "happy path" code, and might not be sufficient for cases where different actions need to be taken for every different branch.

Comment: This code is very hard to read and it only manipulates 2 results for a trivial computation. Extracting methods helps but it is far from perfect, if you don't want to depend on scalaz, you can write the composed type by hand for the specific types you need (see link in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34303208/7898 on how to do this)